# Query to fetch record from 2 tables with ignoring extra records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have 2 tables with below format

```
TableA                   TableB
Aid                      Bid  Month      value
1                        1    October    10
2                        1    November   11
3                        1    December   12
4                        2    November   13
5                        2    December   14 
                         3    September  15
                         3    October    16
                         4    December   17
                         5    September  18
```

With the below query

```
select Aid,Month,value from TableA join TableB on 
Aid=Bid where Month = 'December'
```

I will get the below result set

```
Aid    Month      Value
1      December   12
2      December   14
4      December   17
```

But I need the below result set

```
Aid       Month      Value
1         December   12
2         December   14
3         null       null
4         December   17
5         null       null
```

My intention is we need to return, if bid is in multiple months then we need to return only the december month record and if the bid is not in december month then we need to display only single null record  for that bid.

Finally we need only december month records and if there are no december month records then return null record.

Please help.

Comment: This question is essentially an exact duplicate.  Why doesn't Stack Overflow find these?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN` not `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT Aid,
       Month,
       value
FROM   TableA
       LEFT JOIN TableB
              ON Aid = Bid
                 AND Month = 'December'
```

**Note :** Also you need to move the *filter* to `ON` condition since we are using `LEFT JOIN` and filter column is from `LEFT` table.